# how to apply parallel template definitions in XSLT 2.0

Tags: json, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I'm very new to XSLT, and this sample looked like a great way to learn, but for the life of me can't get it to work. I'm trying to tokenize 2 different strings in parallel and combine them into a JSON array. So I want to tokenize measTypes[0] and match to measResults[0], then measTypes[1] and match to measResults[1], and so on

Sample XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<measInfo measInfoId="1542455297">
    <measTypes>1542455297 1542455298 1542455299 1542455300 1542455301 1542455302 1542455303 1542455304 1542455305 1542455306 1542455307 1542460296 1542460297 </measTypes>
    <measValue measObjLdn="LTHAB0113422/ETHPORT:Cabinet No.=0, Subrack No.=1, Slot No.=7, Port No.=0, Subboard Type=BASE_BOARD">
        <measResults>116967973 585560 496041572 682500 0 12583680 72080 520454 46670568 73432 2205837 1000000 1000000 </measResults>
    </measValue>
    <measValue measObjLdn="LTHAB0113422/ETHPORT:Cabinet No.=0, Subrack No.=1, Slot No.=7, Port No.=1, Subboard Type=BASE_BOARD">
        <measResults>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 </measResults>
    </measValue>
</measInfo>
```

XSLT 2.0 that I have so far

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform” xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema”  exclude-result-prefixes=“xs"  version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="text/plain"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!--
    <xsl:template match="/measInfo/measValue/measResults" name="measRes">
            <xsl:for-each select=".">
            {'measResult':{<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(normalize-space(.),'\s+')"/>}
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    -->
    <xsl:template match="/" name="measObj">
        [
            <xsl:for-each select="measInfo/measValue">
            'measObjLdn':'<xsl:value-of select="@measObjLdn"/>'
            <xsl:call-template name="types"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        ]
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/measInfo" name="types" >
            'Metrics':[
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(normalize-space(measTypes),'\s+')">
                {'measType':'<xsl:value-of select="."/>'},<!-- <xsl:call-template name="measRes"/> -->
            </xsl:for-each>
            ]
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The JSON results I'm hoping for

```html
 [
            'measObjLdn':"LTHAB0113422/ETHPORT:Cabinet No.=0, Subrack No.=1, Slot No.=7, Port No.=0, Subboard Type=BASE_BOARD",
            'Metrics':[
                {'measType':'1542455297','measResult':116967973},
                {'measType':'1542455298','measResult':585560},
                {'measType':'1542455299','measResult':496041572},
                {'measType':'1542455300','measResult':682500},
                {'measType':'1542455301','measResult':0},
                {'measType':'1542455302','measResult':12583680},
                {'measType':'1542455303','measResult':72080},
                {'measType':'1542455304','measResult':520454},
                {'measType':'1542455305','measResult':46670568},
                {'measType':'1542455306','measResult':73432},
                {'measType':'1542455307','measResult':2205837},
                {'measType':'1542460296','measResult':1000000},
                {'measType':'1542460297','measResult':1000000}
            ]
            'measObjLdn':"LTHAB0113422/ETHPORT:Cabinet No.=0, Subrack No.=1, Slot No.=7, Port No.=1, Subboard Type=BASE_BOARD",
            'Metrics':[
                {'measType':'1542455297','measResult':0},
                {'measType':'1542455298','measResult':0},
                {'measType':'1542455299','measResult':0},
                {'measType':'1542455300','measResult':0},
                {'measType':'1542455301','measResult':0},
                {'measType':'1542455302','measResult':0},
                {'measType':'1542455303','measResult':0},
                {'measType':'1542455304','measResult':0},
                {'measType':'1542455305','measResult':0},
                {'measType':'1542455306','measResult':0},
                {'measType':'1542455307','measResult':0},
                {'measType':'1542460296','measResult':0},
                {'measType':'1542460297','measResult':0}
            ]
        ]
```

Comment: `'measObjLdn':{LTHAB0113422/ETHPORT:Cabinet No.=0` does not look like JSON to me.

Comment: Sorry about that, too much cutting and pasting all the code snippets. Should be correct now

Comment: You will need to write a template or function taking two sequences as parameters and then build the JSON object literal for the pair of the first item in each sequence and call the template respectively function on the tail of the sequences. XPath 3.0 has `for-each-pair` for doing that but of course you can implement that yourself in your own function. https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-for-each-pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to process two sequences pairwise:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output media-type="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="measInfo">
        <xsl:variable name="types" select="tokenize(normalize-space(measTypes), '\s+')"/>
        [
          <xsl:apply-templates select="measValue">
            <xsl:with-param name="types" select="$types"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        ]
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="measValue">
        <xsl:param name="types"/>
        { 'measObjLdn' : '<xsl:value-of select="@measObjLdn"/>' },
        <xsl:variable name="values" select="tokenize(normalize-space(), '\s+')"/>
          'Metrics' : 
            [
            <xsl:for-each select="$types">
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                <xsl:if test="$pos > 1">,
                </xsl:if>
                { 'measTypes' : '<xsl:value-of select="."/>', 'measResult' : '<xsl:value-of select="$values[$pos]"/>' } 
            </xsl:for-each>
            ]
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is not well-formatted but you should be able to improve that using `xsl:text` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

XPath 3.0 (and therefore XSLT 3.0) has features you can combine to do just this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="for-each-pair(tokenize(measTypes), tokenize(measInfo/measValue), function($t, $v) {
  serialize(map{'measType':$t, 'measValue':$v}, map{'method':'json'})
})" separator=",&#a;"/>
```